# From Glut and Glew to Qt opengl?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'd like to use Qt for GUI, so I don't need GLUT for windowing anymore, but here is the problem:

I'm in serious trouble since everything is different and Qt doesn't support OpenGL 4.x, Also I used Extended Glew library and I'm not sure if QT support all Glew features for modern OpenGL context.

I find this tutorial for expanding OpenGL Core profile in Qt:
http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/How_to_use_OpenGL_Core_Profile_with_Qt

But still doubt about compatibility issues with Glew, and I'm not sure if I can move the whole project into Qt with success.

So how do you transfer an OpenGL framework (which is based on the GLUT and GLEW) into Qt's OpenGL library?

Comment: "QT doesn't support OpenGL 4.x" In what way does Qt not support GL 4.x. GLEW talks to OpenGL, not Qt or whatever else you use to initialize OpenGL. So GLEW doesn't even know if Qt's there. And about what do you "need advice"? I don't see a question here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7562/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-ndv)

Comment: Qt has nothing to do with and cannot change the underlying features of the OpenGL driver. Nicol is perfectly right with everything he said.

Comment: Ok folks, we need to rein in the comments here. As it currently stands your question is vague and too broad. Wide sweeping  statements/questions such as *"I'm not sure if I can move the whole project into Qt with success."* and *"So how do you transfer an OpenGL framework (which is based on the GLUT and GLEW) into Qt's OpenGL library?"* cannot be reasonably answered. You need to give us a concrete example of your friction points.

Comment: at least remove some of the Nicol comments to make it look fair, many hungry eyes out there... they come to see yet another !SO drama -free beer included. *{I will reflect the story in the Github meetings and blog space}*

Comment: Please stop destroying your questions. This is unacceptable behavior. I have flagged for moderator attention and rolled back a number of your "edits"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Also I used Extended Glew library and I'm not sure if QT support all Glew features for modern OpenGL context.

GLEW is completely independent from the toolkit used. GLEW is neither tied to GLUT nor to Qt. And Qt doesn't care about extensions. Just keep using GLEW together with Qt. *GLEW doesn't interact with the application framework toolkit.*

So replace just GLUT with Qt, but keep the rest as it is.

Comment: In the current Qt5.1 implementation are also features for handling OpenGL function pointers and extensions. Also the OpenGL 4.x is supported. A good jump start tutorial is shown here http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/ .

Answer (score 2):

> I feel like Nokia push me to use Qt for everything, even Shader-Program loader, but that's not what I want from Qt and I can't rewrite the whole project.
>
> So how do you transfer an OpenGL framework (which is based on the GLUT and GLEW) into Qt's OpenGL library?

Nokia is not "pushing" you to do anything. They're simply offering a convenience library for those who want it. If you don't want to rewrite your whole project, you do not have to. Just don't use "Qt's OpenGL library" and you'll be fine.

In short: you answered your own question. If you are willing to rewrite your code to use their library, then you can just use their docs for it. If you're not willing to do it, as you clearly indicate, then you shouldn't use their convenience libraries at all. Just create a `GLWidget` object and use your own stuff.

I promise you: Nokia will not send the police after you if you don't use their `GLShaderProgram` class ;)